# redux form not able to store the input value and always return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

i am trying to use simple redux form in my react login page ,but when i try the console out values in my email and password field they are allways returned undefined.

This is my **signin.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Signin extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit({ email, password }){
    console.log(email,password);
    console.log(this.props.email);
  }

  render(){
    const {  fields: { email, password }, handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))} >
            <fieldset className="form-group" >
             <label>Email:</label>
             <input {...email} className="form-control" component="input" />
             {console.log(email)}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset className="form-group" >
             <label>password:</label>
             <input {...password} className="form-control"  />
            </fieldset>
            <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary"> sign in</button>
        </form>
       );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'signin',
    fields: ['email','password']
})(Signin);
```

this my **index.js** in reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form
});

export default rootReducer;
```

this is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-form": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

i have done all the searching but still not able to find solution for this weird problem.

my input values always return undefined .

Comment: The problem is that you obviously didn't read the documentation of `redux-form` or at least looked at the most basic examples there. 

You need to use the redux-forms `<Field>` component instead of plain `<input>` elements. I'm wondering what "done all the searching" means for you but from my point of view that means at least, that you studied the documentation of the frameworks you want to use.

Comment: thanku...i got my mistake..and corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I did not use FieldSet yet, but you have to define for redux-form the name of each field. I used Field components it has name property. With FieldSet it seems to me you have to use the model property to define an identifier for redux-form.

Comment: ty for your reply sir